# AWS Device Farm File upload 5MB Limit

Tags: aws-device-farm

Callinig **sendKeys** to upload a **Remote file** to `AWS Device Farm desktop`

I'm getting this error:

```
1 validation error detected: Value at 'payload' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 5000000
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `AWS Device Farm` has a **5MB file limitation**.

I could not find any documentation to support that.

Comment: Hello Gal, what's the size of remote file you are trying to upload ? Currently AWS Device Farm Desktop Browser Testing has 5MB limitation for any selenium action payload.

Comment: Yes. That's what I thought - it's 6MB file size.
As to April 2020 there is no documentation of 5MB file size.

Comment: Payload limit is documented now in following link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/testgrid/techref-limits.html. New Payload limit is 15 MB